# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - installing Qt 4.8.5 and Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I found the official guide about [how to install Qt 4.8.5 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-x11.html)

But that approach requires building *Qt SDK* (which may take some time) and setting everything manually. Moreover I need also fulfil [this requirements](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-x11.html).

Later I need also install *Qt Creator*, but when I use a terminal:

```
  sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

it will also install *Qt 5* as a dependency and I get a big mess.

How to install *Qt 4.8.5* and *Qt Creator* from terminal using `apt-get`? Or maybe exists some other way?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, then open `synaptic package manager`. Install `qt4-default` and remove `qt5-default`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I didn't found qt4-default package but I found qtcreator + qtcreatordbg + qtcreatordoc (version 2.4.1 which is connected with Qt4) I install those packages and many dependencies like  some qt libs and qmake were installed automatically. But I noticed that some qt libs (dependencies) weren't installed, for example qt4-qtconfig - why ? Moreover why Synaptic see other version of qtcreator than apt-get ?

Comment: Hmm..
I don't know how to explain it better because sometimes `apt-get` installs the latest version of package and sometimes not. Because in your case `apt-get` installs qt5 instead of qt4. In my case (long time ago when installing gcc) `apt-get` installs gcc-4.6.3 instead of gcc-4.7.2. But I like using `synaptic` because it is easier to search for depedencies. Sorry if I can't give a proper answer. :)